# Can SDL work on Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, sdl

Recently, I've see the Ubuntu Touch video here http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=cpWHJDLsqTU

I want to try to port my own game (using SDL and OGRE) from PC to Ubuntu Tablets.
However it said that the developing will be based on QT and Python. Can SDL(and Ogre) work on it?

Answer (score 1):

It will be usable with Mir as SDL has added support for Mir.

> With Mir and SDL playing nice together, games using it will run natively under Unity 8 on Mir – no fuss, no hassle, and no discernible difference from that of the traditional X server.

Mir is the display server used in last ubuntu versions developped by cannonical

**Reference:** [Some of Linux’s Most Popular Games Will Run Natively On Mir](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/02/mir-sdl-support)